# Parsing JSON with multiple arrays and showing results in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

I am new to front end developing and I'm just starting up. There is a assignment that I would like to figure out and perhaps someone can help on how to parse JSON consisting of multiple arrays and objects. The array list should be shown in HTML radio button and upon marking radio buttons on Submit the proper answer should be shown.

JSON file:

```
{
"quiz": {
    "q1": {
        "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
        "options": [
            "New York Bulls",
            "Los Angeles Kings",
            "Golden State Warriros",
            "Huston Rocket"
        ],
        "answer": "Huston Rocket"
    },
    "q2": {
        "question": "'Namaste' is a traditional greeting in which Asian language?",
        "options": [
            "Hindi",
            "Mandarin",
            "Nepalese",
            "Thai"
        ],
        "answer": "Hindi"
    },
    "q3": {
        "question": "The Spree river flows through which major European capital city?",
        "options": [
            "Berlin",
            "Paris",
            "Rome",
            "London"
        ],
        "answer": "Berlin"
    },
    "q4": {
        "question": "Which famous artist had both a 'Rose Period' and a 'Blue Period'?",
        "options": [
            "Pablo Picasso",
            "Vincent van Gogh",
            "Salvador Dalí",
            "Edgar Degas"
        ],
        "answer": "Pablo Picasso"
    }
}
}
```

Below is image of HTML and how it should look...

[HTML example link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9n9.jpg)

The code that I have written but it's not working, I just tried to show the first array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content=
"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>AJAX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            fetch('http://localhost/itacademy/quiz.json').then(function (response) {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error("Error while reading file.");
                }
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (quiz) {
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<h2>' + quiz.q1.question + '</h2>';
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Please select your answer:</p>';
                        for (let i = 0; i < quiz.q1.options.lenght; i++) {
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" id="bulls" name="team" value="bulls"><label for="bulls">' + quiz[i].q1.options + '</label><br>';
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" id="kings" name="team" value="kings"><label for="kings">' + quiz[i].q1.options + '</label><br>';
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" id="warriros" name="team" value="warriros"><label for="warriros">' + quiz[i].q1.options + '</label><br>';
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" id="rocket" name="team" value="rocket"><label for="rocket">' + quiz[i].q1.options + '</label><br>';
                }
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Answer: ' + quiz.q1.answer + '</p>';
                
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Fetch problem: ' + err.message);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```then(function (response)...``` response.quiz instead of quiz immediately.

Comment: `quiz` in your logic is the variable pointing to the entire response object.  Which has a child key of `quiz`.  So the access pattern with what you have would be `quiz.quiz.q1`.  You're missing one part of the chain.

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit too bland, try to be more concise, if it wont work as expected show us the error. 

The first step to get what maybe the issue is try to get what the json request is responding and try to solve this problem before the others.

BTW as I remember if you try to get json only loading a index.html without a server you'll get a cors error.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are multiple arrays in a JSON you just need to use `JSON.parse(jsonObject)` method to transform the JSON into a javascript object, then you can access the elements as per your need.

Comment: Really?  Pop open your developer tools, go to your console and try `JSON.parse('[],[]')` or `JSON.parse('{},{}')`

Comment: @Anton  That's my point.  This answer seems to be saying that if the json consists of multiple arrays, which is not valid as root elements, that you can just parse it and it will work.  I'm offering examples that this is not so.

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious that JSON.parse() only works for the valid JSON objects so i was only referring to valid JSONs in my answer. Incase of invalid JSON the method won't even work.

Comment: Plus the question is how can i parse a JSON with multiple arrays and objects and the answer is using the JSON.parse() method :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from the start:
as Taplar said the main problem with accessing the objects properties is not using the 'quiz'. The "quiz" in your code refers to a variable in script that contains the "quiz" object

> So the access pattern with what you have would be quiz.quiz.q1

Then for the for loop:
You're using a loop to output data one element by one yet you hardcoded all 4 options yourself so in result you'll get 16 options in your document. 4 for each option. It's pointless. There'll also be spelling mistake so if you insist on using the loop then correct `quiz.q1.options.lenght` to `quiz.quiz.q1.options.length`

Lastly you won't be accessing elements as `quiz[i].q1.options` but `quiz.quiz.q1.options[i]` because it's the 'options' array you're iterating through and not the quiz itself.

Overally you should start with thinking bout the structure of the whole thing as it won't have any chance to work properly atm. If you want to make use of that loop the only reasonable way to keep it is to use it somewhat like that:

```
quiz.q1.options.forEach((entry) => {
    const withoutSpaces = entry.replaceAll(' ', '');
    document.body.innerHTML += `<input type="radio" id="${withoutSpaces}" name="team" value="${withoutSpaces}"><label for="${withoutSpaces}">${entry}</label><br>`
});
```

So the whole thing should look more like this (though I'd say you should really think it through if you want to code it like that):

```
fetch('jsonTest.json').then(function (response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error("Error while reading file.");
    }
    return response.json();
}).then(function (quiz) {
    quiz = quiz.quiz;

    document.body.innerHTML += '<h2>' + quiz.q1.question + '</h2>';
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Please select your answer:</p>';

    quiz.q1.options.forEach((entry) => {
        const withoutSpaces = entry.replaceAll(' ', '');
        document.body.innerHTML += `<input type="radio" id="${withoutSpaces}" name="team" value="${withoutSpaces}"><label for="${withoutSpaces}">${entry}</label><br>`
    });

    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Answer: ' + quiz.q1.answer + '</p>';

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Fetch problem: ' + err.message);
});
```